# MySQL doing a self join to combine records with common IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, activerecord

I have a table with the following schema:

```
mysql> desc player_salaries;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| position      | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| team          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| opponent      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ppg           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| salary        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| injury_status | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| site_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gamedate      | date         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sport_id      | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What's odd here is that 1 player has 4 rows for every single `gamedate` and each row belongs to a different `site_id`. So to get a salary for every single `site` for a specific player on a specific date I can write a query like the following:

`SELECT salary,site_id from player_salaries where player_id = ? AND gamedate = ?`

What I want though is instead of getting 4 rows with the above query, is to have one row returned per player with each `site_id`'s salary in its own column. Is this possible using a `SELF JOIN` type query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `join` the table back to itself as your title suggests.

```
SELECT ps1.salary, 
       ps2.salary, 
       ps3.salary, 
       ps4.salary
FROM player_salaries ps
    JOIN player_salaries ps1 ON 
         ps.player_id = ps1.player_id AND 
         ps.gamedate = ps1.gamedate AND
         ps1.site_id = 1
    JOIN player_salaries ps2 ON 
         ps.player_id = ps2.player_id AND 
         ps.gamedate = ps2.gamedate AND
         ps2.site_id = 2
    JOIN player_salaries ps3 ON 
         ps.player_id = ps3.player_id AND 
         ps.gamedate = ps3.gamedate AND
         ps3.site_id = 3
    JOIN player_salaries ps4 ON 
         ps.player_id = ps4.player_id AND 
         ps.gamedate = ps4.gamedate AND
         ps4.site_id = 4
WHERE ps.player_id = ? AND ps.gamedate = ?
```

Alternatively, a simpler approach would be to use `MAX` with `CASE`:

```
Select Max(Case When Site_id = 1 Then salary end) salary1,
    Max(Case When Site_id = 2 Then salary end) salary2,
    Max(Case When Site_id = 3 Then salary end) salary3,
    Max(Case When Site_id = 4 Then salary end) salary4
From player_salaries 
where ps.player_id = ? AND ps.gamedate = ?
Group by player_id
```

Comment: This is great. I need to go read up on `Max()` and also work on having the way data is stored changed a bit. I guess the thought behind the original design was instead of changing the schema every time a site is added we can just instead insert a row and fill in the correct `site_id`. Not sure if that's ideal anymore.

Comment: @randombits -- No worries, glad I could help.  I'd say your current schema is the correct way to store the data.  The issue here is presenting the data, which is generally better suited for your presentation logic than your database.